# Showing stashes at the position of their parent commit

Tags: git, git-log, git-stash

I'm using the following command to list all my commits:

```
git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all
```

This shows only one entry for my stashes. This entry is at the position of the the last commit from which I started a stash.

Is it also possible to show each stash at it parent commit?

Say I have the following git-log:

```
* 063b893 (HEAD, master) first commit
* 4e6efb9 initial commit
```

After adding a stash:

```
*   51eb834 (refs/stash) WIP on master: 063b893 first commit
|\  
| * dfafaaf index on master: 063b893 first commit
|/  
* 063b893 (HEAD, master) first commit
* 4e6efb9 initial commit
```

After adding a second stash (**Problem 1**: only the last stash is shown):

```
*   1e9b384 (refs/stash) WIP on master: 063b893 first commit
|\  
| * 4862a3d index on master: 063b893 first commit
|/  
* 063b893 (HEAD, master) first commit
* 4e6efb9 initial commit
```

After adding a second commit, stash is still show in the correct position:

```
* c09a3fc (HEAD, master) second commit
| *   1e9b384 (refs/stash) WIP on master: 063b893 first commit
| |\  
|/ /  
| * 4862a3d index on master: 063b893 first commit
|/  
* 063b893 first commit
* 4e6efb9 initial commit
```

After adding another stash and commit (**Problem 2**: stashes that were made directly after `first commit` are not shown. The only stash shown is after `second commit`):

```
* d86c140 (HEAD, master) third commit
| *   4efd3e0 (refs/stash) WIP on master: c09a3fc second commit
| |\  
|/ /  
| * 5065abe index on master: c09a3fc second commit
|/  
* c09a3fc second commit
* 063b893 first commit
* 4e6efb9 initial commit
```

I'd expected to see:

```
* d86c140 (HEAD, master) third commit
| *   4efd3e0 (refs/stash) WIP on master: c09a3fc second commit
| |\  
|/ /  
| * 5065abe index on master: c09a3fc second commit
|/  
* c09a3fc second commit
| *   1e9b384 (refs/stash) WIP on master: 063b893 first commit
| *   51eb834 (refs/stash) WIP on master: 063b893 first commit
| |\  
|/ /  
| * 4862a3d index on master: 063b893 first commit
|/  
* 063b893 first commit
* 4e6efb9 initial commit
```

Comment: The position from the last commit could be considered to be its parent.  Could you post what that graph looks like and where you're confused?  I would expect the stash ref to point to the position in history where I was at when I stashed my code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `--all` simply looks at all the references, and `stash` is exactly one reference, giving *the* (latest/current) stash.

Where are all the other stashes?  They're hiding away in the `refs/stash` reflog.  `--all` does not extract reflogs and `--decorate` does not examine reflogs.

You can get the other stashes to show up by calling them out explicitly:

```
git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all stash@{1} stash@{2}
```

(this assumes three total stashes, `--all` gets one and we add the other two here; it requires a little bit of scripting or similar to programmatically count `stash` reflog entries and add the appropriate number of `stash@{n}` items), but they won't get decorations.